# Highlight a cell with conditional logic (for html, R Markdown output)

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I want to highlight certain cells in a table.

For example, highlight all cells where `total_n_obs > 5000`.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTEpo.jpg)

I have seen solutions from ~2 years ago (which use CSS or pander) but have not been able to implement them.

Is there a way to code this directly into an RMarkdown script?

Thanks a lot, I really appreciate any help/ideas!

Comment: What solutions have you seen and where are you stuck with the implementation?

Comment: Apparently the function "formatStyle" from the DT package can highlight certain columns, but I don't believe the it can do so conditionally. (Even if I try it without conditional logic I still get an error:  general_table <- formatStyle(general_table, c(1,3), color="red", backgroundColor="orange", fontWeight="bold")
Error in !rownames : invalid argument type

Comment: The first result I get if I Google "pandoc highlight cells" gives me a help page that points out `emphasize` and says it can be used with `which(..., arr.ind = TRUE)`. If you can post some sample data and indicate which cells you want highlighted, that might be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To highlight text change the background-color style of `total_n_obs` column, as shown in the example below. (I have created a new column using the plyr::summarise command)

```
library(plyr)

df2 <- adply(df,1,
summarise, total_n_obs_t = ifelse(total_n_obs >= 5000,
paste('<div style="background-color: yellow; text-align: right;">',total_n_obs,'</div>',sep=""),
          paste('<div style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right;">',total_n_obs,'</div>',sep="")
                                 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply George. Following your code, a new column, total_n_obs_t,  is created . How does this translate into a colors? I see that the text states, "background-color: yellow" but that doesn't make the cell automatically yellow. I think I am missing a step that goes from this new dataframe with the newly created column, to an output. Would you mind giving me a little more help? Thanks, appreciated.